# Get contents of a series of p elements and place in their own div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a DOM structure that contains a series of any one or all of these three types of `<p>` tags in random order:

```
<p>Some text</p>            <!-- a <p> with only text -->
<p><img src="someImg"></p>  <!-- a <p> with only an <img> -->
<p>                         <!-- a <p> with both text and <img> -->
  <img src="anotherImg">
  Some other text
</p>
...                         <!-- Random combination of these <p> tags -->
```

I need to change the DOM structure to place everything in it's own `<div>` along with a class that indicates if the original `<p>` tag containd only one thing or both:

```
<div class="single">        <!-- From <p> tag with only text -->
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="single">        <!-- From <p> tag with only an <img> -->
  <img src="someImg">
</div>

<div class="double">        <!-- <img> from <p> tag with both text & <img> -->
  <img src="anotherImg>
</div>

<div class="double">        <!-- <p> from <p> tag with both text & <img> -->
  <p>Some other text</p>
</div>
```

I've had some sucess getting the `<p>` tags with only an `<img>` tag or text into their own `<div>` using jQuery:

```
$('#content').find('img').each(function(index, element) {
  var parentTag = $(this).parent().get(0).tagName;
  if (parentTag == 'P') {
    $(this).parent().contents().unwrap();
  }
  $(this).wrap('<div class=\"single\"></div>');
});

$('#content').find('p').each(function(index, element) {
  $(this).wrap('<div class=\"single\"></div>');
});
```

But I am having trouble getting the `<p>` tags, which contain both an image and text into their own separate `<div>` tags with a separate class.

I don't necessarily need this to be done using jQuery. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the `p` nodes. Then iterate over the nodeList to check if the current element has an image and text. For the text validation use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

```js
(function() {

  function extractImage(el) {
    var img = el.querySelector('img');
    if (!img) return null;
    el.removeChild(img);
    return img;
  }

  function wrap(el, cls, isDouble) {
    var img = extractImage(el);
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.classList.add(cls);
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);
    if (isDouble && img) {
      var imageWrapper = document.createElement('div');
      el.parentNode.insertBefore(imageWrapper, el);
      imageWrapper.appendChild(img);
      imageWrapper.classList.add(cls);
    }
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    if (!isDouble && img) el = img;
    wrapper.appendChild(el);
  }

  function hasImageAndText(el) {
    return el.querySelector('img') && el.textContent.trim() ? true : false;
  }

  document.querySelectorAll('#content p:not(:empty)').forEach(el => {
    if (hasImageAndText(el)) wrap(el, 'double', true);
    else wrap(el, 'single');
  });


})();
```

```css
.single {
  background-color: gold;
}

.double {
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p><img src="//placehold.it/50"></p>
  <p>
    <img src="//placehold.it/50"> Some other text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That works for setting the class but when both an image and text are in the same `<p>` tag I need to separate them into their own `<div>` tag.

Comment: I was not aware of that requirement, the answer is updated now.

Comment: That mostly does everything I need. With this code, the images which are alone in a `<p>` tag are still wrapped by the `<p>` tag in addition to the new `<div>`. I believe this line `el.parentNode.removeChild(el);` should remove the extra `<p>` tag, but it doesn't seem to be doing so. Also wouldn't that also remove everything inside the `<p>` tag including the image?

Comment: I have fixed that issue, please check it out.